# Opencart header editing does not work in the live website

Tags: php, header, opencart, opencart-3, opencart-module

I install opencart locally and edit the header. Changes are shown but the same file I put in the C panel just header changes are not working. Other all pages show the modified work except the header. Even I delete the header file but the default opencart was also shown. From where default header comes? In the admin, these errors are shown  PHP Warning:

> unlink(/home/zeromyvb/smartview_storage/cache/cache.stock_status.1.1638804472):
> No such file or directory in
> /home/zeromyvb/smartview.com.bd/system/library/cache/file.php on line
> 17
>
> PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent
> by (output started at
> /home/zeromyvb/smartview.com.bd/system/framework.php:42) in
> /home/zeromyvb/smartview.com.bd/catalog/controller/startup/session.php
> on line 25
>
> PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent
> by (output started at
> /home/zeromyvb/smartview.com.bd/system/framework.php:42) in
> /home/zeromyvb/smartview.com.bd/catalog/controller/startup/startup.php
> on line 107
>
> PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent
> by (output started at
> /home/zeromyvb/smartview.com.bd/system/framework.php:42) in
> /home/zeromyvb/smartview.com.bd/catalog/controller/startup/startup.php
> on line 167

I tried lots of ways. delete cache but the same problem is shown.

Comment: please provide more details:
1. what files have you deleted (their paths)
2. what files have you edited (their paths and the code you added)
3. do you have a custom theme ?

Answer (score 0):

Examine permissions and the path to the DIR_STORAGE directory within the config.php and admin/config.php files and replace the relative path with an absolute path for DIR_STORAGE.

Answer (score 0):

before > check DIR_STORAGE & DIR_SYSTEM in config.php

1- remove all cache files from > root/system/cache/*

2- remove all modification files and folder from > root/system/modification/*

3- run refresh modification link in admin section

4- check folders permission > logs + cache + modification

Answer (score 0):

In OpenCart Admin go to extensions/modifications and press the refresh button a few times.

On slower servers you might have to wait a minute.